# How to get user data with httpOnly cookie in React/NodeJS authentication flow

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies

I am developing a React/Redux client with a NodeJS/Express backend.
The react app runs on port 3000 and the backend on port 443.

This React App has 3 react-router Routes (SignUp, Login and Home, the last one is protected and only accessible for authenticated users).

When user logs in, the React app makes a post request to the backend with email and password. The server searches the user in a mongoDB database and returns a `res.cookie` with `httpOnly` flag.

The cookie is a jwt with some information, for example the `isAdmin` flag. The Home route in the client has different options depending if the user is admin or not.

How can my React client securely know if a user has logged in and whether a user is admin or not?

I have found 2 solutions:

- Use localStorage/sessionStorage instead of a httpOnly cookie but I am told that this is very insecure.
- Remove the httpOnly flag, so that my client can read the cookie. I have tested this and works great, but again, the security risk is what I find disturbing.

I sense I am missing something in the authentication flow.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I know of is to have an endpoint on your backend where the client can retrieve the user information (e.g /users/me).

Basically, when your application mounts you will send a request to this endpoint, get the user information and then the user can start accessing different routes in your React app.

One drawback to this approach is when you are on a development environment, with every change that you make on the frontend you will be pinging this backend endpoint because of the hot reloading.